# Setting a timeout for pysftps' get()

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

[pysftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp)'s `get()` method sometime hangs.

For example if I execute the following to download a file:

```
import pysftp #pip install sftp
import sys

hostname = "128.65.45.12"
username = "bob"       
password = "123456"  

sftp = pysftp.Connection(hostname, username=username, password=password)
while True:
    sftp.get('/data/word_vectors/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt', preserve_mtime=True)
    print('done')
```

It may display a few "done", i.e. download the file a few times, but then hangs for ever (while the server is still responsive). How can I set a timeout for pysftps' get() to restart it if it hangs?

Comment: `signal.alarm()` may do the trick as demonstrated in the python docs [signal example](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/signal.html#example). I don't have `pysftp` so haven't tested it.